# How to fetch data from ul li in android studio with jsoup

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

I am trying to get Product 1 and Product 2 but I cant get it help please
I am using `jsoup` and volley

```
<ul id="searched-products">
    <li>
        <div class="gd-col navUnitContainer1 gu4">
            <div class="product_name">
                <a>Prodict 1</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="gd-col navUnitContainer1 gu4">
            <div class="product_name">
                <a>Prodict 2</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I have tried this

```
Elements itemElements = doc.select("ul#searched-products li");
```

but its not selecting "li".I have also tried this

```
Elements itemElements = doc.select("ul#searched-products"); //this line works
Element e1 = itemElements.get(i);
e1.select("li"); or item.getElementsByTag("li");
```

still no good...
There are hundreds of li so I cant do this

```
doc.select("li");
```

Kindly suggest something

Comment: Any reason you don't want to get all `a` or  `div.product_name`s?

Comment: getting a is also fine but i cant get it

Comment: `doc.select("a")` doesn't work?

Comment: i am trying to get data from a website and on thoses pages there are hundreds of "a" but i need data from these specific tags

Comment: Okay, then `div.product_name a`?

Comment: Note that if your page is dynamically generated with Javascript, then Jsoup can't parse it

Comment: Iterate the li Array and select further down.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
public class JsoupList {

public static void main(String[] brawwwr){
    String html = "<ul id=\"searched-products\">" +
"<li>" +
    "<div class=\"gd-col navUnitContainer1 gu4\">" +
        "<div class=\"product_name\">" +
            "<a>Prodict 1</a>" + 
        "</div>" + 
    "</div>" +
"</li>" +
"<li>" +
    "<div class=\"gd-col navUnitContainer1 gu4\">" +
        "<div class=\"product_name\">"+
            "<a>Prodict 2</a>" +
        "</div>" +
    "</div>" +
"</li>" +
"</ul>";

    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

    Elements itemElements = doc.select("ul#searched-products li");

    for(Element elem : itemElements){

        System.out.println(elem.select("div div a").text());
    }
}

}
```

Will return

Prodict 1

Prodict 2

You can imagine repetitive code inside tags like a little page of its own.
regards

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code.**

```
Elements itemElements = doc.select("ul#searched-products");
itemElements = itemElements.select("li");
for(Element ele : itemElements){
String text = ele.text();
System.out.println(text); //this will return Prodict 1 and Prodict 2 
}

//  or u can try by getting all the a

for(Element ele : itemElements){
 String text = ele.select("a").first().text();
 System.out.println(text); //this will also return Prodict 1 and Prodict 2
}
```

Comment: @user8494167 did u try this ?

Answer (score 0):

To exclude `<li>` or `<a>` tags outside the list, you need to restrict the selector to match only inside the list. The best would be to use the ID (`#searched-products`). Then do not select `<li>` or `<a>` tags from the `doc`, but from the selected `<ul>`element.

You can get your text with any of the following selectors (not a complete list):

- `#searched-products li a`
- `#searched-products a`
- `#searched-products .product_name a`
- `#searched-products .product_name`

Even the last one is okay, since you need only the text, and `div.product_name` contains only the `<a>` tag.

```
for(Element e: doc.select("#searched-products .product_name")) {
    String t = e.text(); // Prodict N
}
```

By the way, **your original approach with selecting `<li>` tags inside `ul#searched-products` should have worked.** If that doesn't return anything, the case might be that the list is generated dynamically on that page. You can test it easily by printing out the HTML that Jsoup has (`doc.html()` or `doc.select('#searched-products').html()`).

If really that's the case, Jsoup is not the right tool for you. I suggest you to use [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) with possibly a headless browser ([HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) or [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/)). They can return and even interact with dynamically created elements, so maybe other parts of your crawl process can be simplified.